# Updating child property of viewmodel in .net Maui

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

So I have a ViewModel for a page on Maui .Net, and it looks like this:

```
namespace SnookerScorer.ViewModels
{
    public partial class SixRedsView : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public int totalPoints = 75;

        [ObservableProperty]
        Player player1 = new Player();

        [ObservableProperty]
        Player player2 = new Player();

        [RelayCommand]
        public void IncreasePlayer1Score(string value)
        {
            int numValue = int.Parse(value);
            int updatedScore = Player1.Score + numValue;
            Player1.Score = updatedScore;
        }
    }

}
```

And the Player class looks like this:

```
namespace SnookerScorer.DataModels
{
    public partial class Player
    {
        private int score;

        public int Score
        {
            get => score;
            set
            {
                score = value;
            }
        }
       
        public Player() 
        {
            this.score = 0;
        }

        public void UpdateScore(int num)
        {
            score += num;
        }

    }
}
```

And the xaml file for the page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SnookerScorer.Views.SixRedsRules"
             Title=""
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" 
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SnookerScorer.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:SixRedsView">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView 
            Grid.Column="0"
            Color="White"/>
        <Label
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="{Binding Player1.Score}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            />
        
        <BoxView
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Color="White"/>
        <Label
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding Player2.Score, Mode=TwoWay}"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            />

        <BoxView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Color="White"
            />
        
        <Button
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            CornerRadius="100"
            WidthRequest="100"
            HeightRequest="100"
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            Command="{Binding IncreasePlayer1ScoreCommand}"
            CommandParameter="10"
            />

        <BoxView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Color="White"
            />

        <Label
            x:Name="PointsAvailable"
            Text="{Binding TotalPoints}"
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            />
    </Grid>
    
</ContentPage>
```

What I want to do is update either Player1 or Player2 scores by using the relay command, while debugging it I can see that it does get updated to the correct number, the only problem is that in the UI it doesn't update the value being displayed. I tried making the class Player inherit from ObservableObject, but to no avail.

Is there any way to do this without always creating a new Player object?

Comment: 1) Score needs to be Observable, 2) `score += num;` this is updating the **private** field, not the **public** property.  Only the public property raises a `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: About the second point, I'm not even using the UpdateScore method so in the relay command I'm using the public method.

Comment: The first point actually worked lol, thank you very much.

Comment: If I use the method UpdateScore though it doesn't update the field, even when it's set to be an observable property, is there any way I can make that method work and update the UI automatically?

Comment: did you fix it to update the public property instead of the private field?

Comment: I fixed the method to update the public property, but I just realized that I cannot make it work, I can't make Score to be observable as only properties can be observable and not fields.

Comment: Score is a property.  I don’t understand your comment

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to update the property `Score` of **Model** `Player`, the `Player` also needs to inherit from `ObservableObject` like below, this will enable it to automatically update the text value of the `Label` displayed which is binding to `Player1.Score`.

```
public class Player : ObservableObject 
{

        private int score;

        public int Score
        {
            get => score;
            set =>SetProperty(ref score, value);            
        }

}
```

Furthermore, you can either update the `Score` of `Player1` or `Player2` via **ReplayCommand** `IncreasePlayer1Score`, if you want to update both, you can refer to the code below:

```
[RelayCommand] 
public void IncreasePlayer1Score(string value)
{
       int numValue = int.Parse(value);

       int updatedScore = player1.Score + numValue;

       player1.Score = updatedScore;

       player2.Score = updatedScore;

}
```

Comment: @Guilherme Takata, I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here. We can work together to figure it out.

Comment: I can confirm that this is working well. However, it would be better if there is a way to add Attribute on top of "Score" so we don't have to define the property and private value separately. ( imagine we may have a model of many properties, but we don't need to override "get" and "set" )